# Buscar valor em uma estrutura JSON usando variáveis como chave

Tags: r, shiny

Tenho um JSON parecido com este abaixo em um arquivo `config.json`

```
[
  {
    "code": "RJ",
    "name": "Rio de Janeiro",
    "levels": {
      "Education": {
        "Secretaria Municipal de Educação": {
          "code": "SME",
          "file": "geo_sme",
          "layer": "layer1"
        },
        "Bairro": {
          "code": "Bairro",
          "file": "geo_bairro",
          "layer": ""
        }
      },
      "Saúde": {
        "Secretaria Municipal de Saúde": {
          "code": "SMS",
          "file": "",
          "layer": ""
        },
        "Bairro": {
          "code": "Bairro",
          "file": "",
          "layer": ""
        }
      },
      "Outro": {
        "Qualquer": {
          "code": "QQ",
           "file": "",
          "layer": ""
        },
       "Outro": {
          "code": "Outro",
          "file": "",
          "layer": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Estou lendo o arquivo conforme abaixo:

```
library(rjson)

cfg_json <- fromJSON(file = "config.json")
```

Montei uma função para pegar o `code` baseado em entradas realizadas pelo usuário em seleção tipo dropdown.

### server.r

```
  observeEvent(input$boundary_menu, {
    choices <- get_code(input$city_menu, input$hierarchy_menu, input$boundary_menu)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "region", choices = choices)
  })
```

```
get_code <- function(city, hierarchy, boundary) {
  d <- Filter(function(x) x$name == city, cfg_json)
  a_code <- d$levels[[hierarchy]][[boundary]]$code
   print(a_code)  # RETORNA NULL
  a_code
}
```

Porém está retornando `NULL`

Já debuguei os valores de `city`, `hierarchy` e `boundary`. Estão corretos.

Comment: Veja em `str(cfg_json)` que `cfg_json` é uma `List of 1`, que essa lista tem 3 membros e que um deles, `levels`, é o membro que quer. E faça `a_code <- d[[1]]$levels[[hierarchy]][[boundary]]$code`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas. Funcionou, obrigado! No entanto, mesmo entendendo que o Filter retorna uma lista, não consigo entender o porque de usar `[[1]]` e não `[[outro_número_qualquer]]`. Você poderia colocar uma resposta completa para que eu possa marcá-la como aceita e entender melhor como a lista é montada, ou seja, o que é cada elemento da mesma?

Answer (score 1):

É uma pergunta mais antiga mas como o colega do comentário acabou não postando uma resposta completa, só para ficar com uma resposta e fechar a pergunta, segue a minha.

### Solução

O erro está na função `Filter()` que você está usando para selecionar o objeto `JSON` correspondente à cidade escolhida pelo usuário. O objeto retornado é uma lista, e você está tentando acessar os campos como um `JSON` diretamente (usando a notação de colchetes duplos, `[[ ]]`).

Para corrigir isso, você pode usar a função `[[]]` para acessar o primeiro elemento da lista retornada pelo `Filter()`, e então continuar acessando os campos do objeto JSON normalmente:

```
get_code <- function(city, hierarchy, boundary) {
  d <- Filter(function(x) x$name == city, cfg_json)[[1]]
  a_code <- d$levels[[hierarchy]][[boundary]]$code
  a_code
}
```

Assim você acessa o primeiro elemento da lista retornada pelo Filter, e após o primeiro elemento é um objeto JSON, e você pode acessar os campos como antes.